# Vaadin 7 - ExecutionException: Push

Tags: java, textarea, push, vaadin

I want to append some textlines to a textarea in my program.

Here's my method `appendText`:

```
protected synchronized void appendText(final String i_text) {
    UI.access(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textarea.setReadOnly(false);
            setText(textarea.getValue() + i_text + "\n");
            textarea.setCursorPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            textarea.setReadOnly(true);
            UI.push();
        }
    });
}
```

Sometimes I see this exceptiontrace in my application, but I don't know why this happen

Can anybody help me?

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Push failed at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) at 
com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession$FutureAccess.get(VaadinSession.java:123) at 
com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.runPendingAccessTasks(VaadinService.java:1800) at 
com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession.unlock(VaadinSession.java:1013) at 
com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.ensureAccessQueuePurged(VaadinService.java:1761) at
com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.accessSession(VaadinService.java:1727) at 
com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession.access(VaadinSession.java:1403) at 
com.vaadin.ui.UI.access(UI.java:1389) at   
abat.spsemulation.ui.components.OutputComponent.appendText(OutputComponent.java:37) at
abat.spsemulation.ui.components.TelegramOutputComponent.appendTelegramText(TelegramOutputComponent.java:27) at abat.sps_emulation.outputlayer.GUIController.info(GUIController.java:1304) at 
abat.sps_emulation.interfaces.TelegramLogger$1.run(TelegramLogger.java:87) at 
java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251) at 
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733) at 
java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692) at
 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76) at vjava.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703) at 
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242) at 
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161) at 
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150) at 
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146) at 
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138) at 
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Push failed at 
com.vaadin.server.communication.AtmospherePushConnection.push(AtmospherePushConnection.java:158) at
com.vaadin.server.communication.AtmospherePushConnection.push(AtmospherePushConnection.java:133) at com.vaadin.ui.UI.push(UI.java:1496) at 
abat.spsemulation.ui.components.OutputComponent$1.run(OutputComponent.java:44) at 
com.vaadin.ui.UI.accessSynchronously(UI.java:1326) at com.vaadin.ui.UI$3.run(UI.java:1392) at 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at 
com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.runPendingAccessTasks(VaadinService.java:1797) ... 23 more Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException at 
java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:926) at 
java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:954) at 
 com.vaadin.ui.ConnectorTracker.cleanConnectorMap(ConnectorTracker.java:300) at 
com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlWriter.write(UidlWriter.java:305) at    
com.vaadin.server.communication.AtmospherePushConnection.push(AtmospherePushConnection.java:155) 
...    31 more
```